# Adding span to each word not in tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am in need of a script which achieves the following:
Placing a span tag around every word, with the exception of words which are already in a tag.

For example the following html:

```
<p>I <span>like</span> to go <b>to</b> the park.</p>
```

Should become:

```
<p><span>I</span> <span>like</span> <span>to</span> <span>go</span> <b>to</b> <span>the</span> <span>park.</span></p>
```

I have thus far succeeded only in placing sentence fragments in the span tags, but not each individual word. (Using this script: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oyb4adff/22/), jQuery is permissable)

```js
$("#tot")
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
    // get only the text nodes
    return this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.trim() !== "";
}).wrap("<span />");
```

```css
span {
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="tot">
I love to <span id="hello">go to</span> the park every <span>day</span> because <b>it is</b> fun.
</p>
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/oyb4adff/52/

```
var result = $("#tot")
.contents()
.map(function () {
    // get only the text nodes
    var newText = "";
    if(this.nodeType === 3) {
      var text = this.nodeValue.trim().split(" ");
      for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
        newText += "<span>" + text[i] + "</span>";
        if(i + 1 < text.length) newText += " ";
      }
      return newText;
    }
    return this.outerHTML;
}).toArray()
.join(" ");
$("#tot").html(result);
```

What I did is:

1. Loop through the contents
2. If it was a regular text node then split it into separate words
3. Add together with spans around them
4. If it was a html node then just add it back in without editing